# How to make object mast an Area of the stage

Tags: actionscript-3

I have searched the web for a solution close to this but didnt find one.
What i mean is that like all tutorials out there 
[like this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4yBS.png)  and [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4yBS.png) you place a picture as a background and then you make a rectangle(or any shape) that is used for unmasking the area where ever you move that rectangle/shape (the mask).

So my question is this: How do i move the rectangle over the stage, but the content that is being revealed stays the same.To show what i mean i present this picture.

[image]

(the actual mask is the box with the red boarder)
So at the start my mask positions itself somewhere at x = 50; y = 250 and then i decide to move it to the right x = 350; y = 250.But I want the mask to show still the same property(or the say it more clearly - the same part of the ellipse which is in the area x = 50 to x= 150 y = 50 to y = 100) of the ellipse.

The reason im doing this is cause here the ellipse is static (cause i want to show what i want to achieve) but what i really want is to make the ellipse move(change its direction), so when i move the mask somewhere it will show that area of the stage and what part of the circle is moving there (the area from x= 50 to x= 150 and y = 50 to y = 100)

So Ill state my question again: How do i make the mask, show an area that i want, no matter where i move the mask ?

the code i have is the same from the links given:

```
[Embed(source = '../../lib/Contrast_by_MaNi3k.png')]
    private var backgroundClass:Class;
    private var background:Bitmap = new backgroundClass();
    private var myMask:Sprite;
    private var myMaskSize:Number = 100;

    public function Main():void 
    {
        if (stage) init();
        else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    private function init(e:Event = null):void 
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        addChild(background);

        myMask = new Sprite();
        myMask.graphics.beginFill(0x00FF00);
        myMask.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, myMaskSize, myMaskSize);
        myMask.x = 350;
        myMask.y = 250;
        addChild(myMask);

        background.mask = myMask;

        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDown);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseReleased);
    }

    private function mouseDown(event:MouseEvent):void {
        myMask.startDrag();
    }

    private function mouseReleased(event:MouseEvent):void {
        myMask.stopDrag();
    }
```

Comment: Not entirely clear. In what way does the mask stay active after you've moved it? What happens to the relationship between the mask and the masked object after you move the mask?     Or do you just want a COPY of your mask that you can put somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you don't actually need a **mask**. You can take a 'picture' of any part of the stage using the **bitMapData** class. You can then create a **BitMap** with that bitMapData and position the bitmap anywhere you want.

You say 'the ellipse is static...' which suggests that it won't be moving and so that you won't have to update the bitMapData 'picture.' But if the ellipse *does* change position, just take another 'picture' of the original area on stage and then re-draw the BitMap.

Comment: ok so from your answer if i have a moving ellipse, ill have to use a function that will clear the graphics from the last frame, copy the graphics of the location in this frame, and them paste the copied graphics in the area of rectangle (that used to be the mask). Is that what you are suggesting? If yes hmmmm can it be done somehow more processor friendly, cause if i have 3-4 "masks" that represent 3-4 different areas of the stage it would get quite laggy

Comment: Ah! I see that you want to move the ellipse! I'll have to think a little more.

Comment: Will you be running this on a fast desktop machine? A mobile device?

Comment: I actualy did something near what i wanted -> [here is the FLA file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5u6hrR2w7UEYkFWdkY4dUJjcGc/edit?usp=sharing),     , but i dont think this is a good solution cause if i have like 10 or 15 elements that track different portion of the main element, i think it will spike a lot or it will consume a lot of processor power